# RenderBox.size with Null check error after upgrade Flutter

Tags: flutter, rendering, upgrade

I upgrade my Flutter version from v2.10.4 to v3.3.10 , amount of errors occure like this:

```
# main(2)

_CastError

Null check operator used on a null value


#0 RenderBox.size (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2023)
#1 RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:253)
#2 RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135)
#3 RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418)
#4 ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56)
#5 RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:836)
#6 RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:938)
#7 RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135)
#8 RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418)
#9 RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120)
#10 RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135)
#11 RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418)
#12 RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120)
#13 _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1462)
#14 RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135)
#15 RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418)
#16 RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120)
#17 _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1462)
#18 RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135)
#19 RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418)
#20 RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:292)
#21 RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135)
#22 RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418)
#23 RenderPositionedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:451)
#24 RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135)
#25 RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418)
#26 RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:249)
#27 RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135)
#28 RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418)
#29 RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120)
#30 RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135)
#31 RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418)
#32 RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120)
#33 RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135)
#34 RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418)
#35 RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120)
#36 RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135)
#37 RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418)
#38 RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120)
#39 RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135)
#40 RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418)
#41 RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120)
#42 RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135)
#43 RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418)
#44 RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120)
#45 RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135)
#46 RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418)
#47 RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120)
#48 RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135)
#49 RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418)
#50 RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120)
#51 RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3737)
#52 RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135)
#53 RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418)
#54 RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120)
#55 RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2135)
#56 RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418)
#57 _RenderTheatre.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:804)
#58 RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1973)
#59 PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:999)
#60 RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:513)
#61 WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:884)
#62 RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:378)
#63 SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1175)
#64 SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1104)
#65 SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1015)
#66 _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1391)
#67 _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1293)
#68 _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1201)
#69 _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:150)
#70 PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:318)
#71 _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115)
```

According to the stack, all of them from the flutter framework. I have no idea to find out where causes this error in my code.

I guess it must a wrong stage during widget rendering.

Can you give me some idea?

My pubspec.yaml like this:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.10.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ^3.3.10
```

Comment: what is `flutter: ^3.3.10`

Comment: my pubspec.yaml declaration。

Comment: can you try with update version+upgrading flutter

Comment: From flutter development on GitHub  "SDK constraints do not change your SDK, they indicate what version of an SDK a package is compatible with.
Flutter isn't a dependency in this context, it's the toolchain.
The only thing putting a Flutter constraint in an app's pubspec will do is cause people trying to build that app with an older version of Flutter to receive an error. That may be useful in some cases, but the main use for this is in published packages." So the suggestion in the comment above is the way to go....then just use a lowest allowed value in pubspec eg.`flutter: ">=3.0.0"`

Comment: Hi @Yeasin ,I upgrade my project's Flutter version without run 'flutter pub upgrade', just modified the pubspec. yaml file. Does it mean i maybe use some old packages with dependencies ,whitch may cause this error?

Comment: Hi @GrahamD ,according the document :https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#flutter-sdk-constraints  You can specifying this Flutter SDK under the environment.

Comment: Yeah, but that's just a constraint....it doesn't automatically upgrade your flutter sdk, you have to do that as a command in the terminal. Have you done that?

Comment: Thanks man, I have run 'flutter pub upgrade' , and many of my packages updeted to latest .

Answer (score 1):

According to the page tracking info, I finally find out this issue:
I use `routes#showGeneralDialog` to display a widget with wrong width.